# How do you set the MS_MAPFILE environment variable in IIS?

Tags: mapserver, iis

I'm trying to set up MapServer as a WMS on a windows server running IIS. All works well until I try to cascade the service through GeoServer and the getcapabilities URL is flagged as invalid as it includes a full path to the map file in it and `:` is not a valid character.

In the short term I can work around this by using a relative path (and `/` instead of `\`) but I'm not happy having external URLs depend on my local file layout, so I looked at hiding the `map=` section of the URL.

This is usually done by setting the `MS_MAPFILE` variable, but I can't work out how to make IIS see it. I even tried setting it in the system environment but it seems to make no difference.

In the good old days when I last tried this I would have wrapped the `.exe` in a `.bat` file and set the variable there to make sure, but IIS won't let me run anything but a `.exe` (or `.dll`).

So is there any way to set an environment variable in IIS so that MapServer can see it.

Comment: Not sure if this old advice http://www.onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/4_4_1.html will help you